# AWS SNS: How to send push notifications to specific tokens only?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

How to send SNS notifications to specific device tokens? And do I need to use Topic ARN and groups If I want to send to specific tokens?

So the idea is that we want to do A/B testing, so we want to grab say 10% random tokens of the tokens we have in the database, a mix between IOS and Android, and send them push notifications.

Therefore we're not sending to groups, we're sending to specific tokens instead. This will run on NodeJS, AWS lambda HTTP function. The content would be

title, subtitle (optional), badge, message text

In short:

1. How to do that?
2. Should I use groups, audience and topic ARNs in this case?

Comment: 1. Public message to specific target arn. 2. No